# Last line repeats when doing fgets/fputs

Tags: c, string, file, fgets, fputs

I'm doing an insertion, that imply **a file**, **a string**, and **a new file** who will receive **all the data of the original file plus the string to be inserted**, and it will replace the original file.

So, for example, my original file:

**data.txt**

```
 line1
 line2
 line3
 line4
 line5
```

will become, with the insertion of the string "newline":

**data_temp.txt** --> renamed later **data.txt**

```
 line1
 line2
 line3
 line4
 line5 
 newline
```

With that purpose, I have the following code:

```
/* FILE variables of the original file and the new file */
FILE *data, *data_temp;
data = fopen( "data.txt", "r" ); 
data_temp = fopen( "data_temp.txt", "w" ); 

/* String buffer */
char buf[256];                      
int i_buf;

/* The string to be inserted in the new file */
char newline[10] = "newline";

/* For each line of the original file, the content of each line 
is written to the new file */
while(!feof(data))              
{
            /* Removing the \n from the string of the line read */
    fgets(buf, MAX_INSERT, data);                   
    for(i_buf = strlen(buf)-1; i_buf && buf[i_buf] < ' '; i_buf--)  
    buf[i_buf] = 0;

            /* Writing the string obtained to the new file */
    fputs(buf, data_temp);
    fputs("\n", data_temp);
}

    /* The string will be inserted at the final of the new file */
if(feof(datos))
{
    fputs(newline, datos_temp);
}

    /* Closing both files */
fclose(data);
fclose(data_temp);

    /* The original file is deleted and replaced with the new file */
remove ("data.txt");
rename ("data_temp.txt", "data.txt");
```

My problem is basically in the writing to the original file, to the new file. **The last line of the original file shows duplicated in the new file**.

In the example given:

**data.txt**

```
 line1
 line2
 line3
 line4
 line5
```

The **line5** (last line of the original file) **is showed twice on the new file**, and then is the string to be inserted.

**data_temp.txt** --> renamed later **data.txt**

```
 line1
 line2
 line3
 line4
 line5 
 line5
 newline
```

I strongly believe the problem is in the reading of the original file (AKA the `while(!feof(data))` loop), on the checking the EOF, the fgets, or the fputs. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: `fgets()` has a return value. It might help if you checked it.

Comment: Are you always appending data like this? If so, open the file in `append` mode, and write the line.

Comment: Why are you going to the trouble of stripping the `newline` from the input, when you immediately write it out again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The problem is in your loop condition.

`feof()` is evil because it's often misunderstood. `feof()` doesn't indicate that you are *at* the end-of-file. It only indicates that it has not yet encountered it (that you haven't fetched a byte past the end of the file).

You must instead detect within the loop when you encounter EOF(when `fgets()` returns `NULL`) and break out of the loop then.

Comment: In fact, I inserted a condition that `fgets` doesn't take the `NULL` value. As long it doesn't take the `NULL` value, I can give the string to the original file to the new file using `fputs`. I tested it right now and it worked.