# Reading line by line in C

Tags: c, file, io

Currently to read a file line by line in C I am using:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
    //do something with each line that is now stored in buffer
}
```

However there is no guarantee in the file that the line will be shorter than 1024. What will happen if a line is longer than 1024? Will the rest of the line be read in the next iteration of the while loop?

And how can I read line by line without a maximum length?

Comment: Most of your question is addressed in the documentation of [**`fgets()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). If you didn't consume the newline, it won't be on the end Regarding reading a dynamic line, write a dynamic buffer expansion algorithm that grows until a newline or EOF is encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the rest of the line will be read in the next iteration.

You can detect whether or not you read a whole line by inspecting the last character of the string (i.e. the one before the null terminator) to see if it is `'\n'` or not -- fgets passes `'\n'` through to you.

There is no Standard C function which will read a line whilst dynamically allocating enough memory for it, however there is a POSIX function `getline()` which does that.  You could write your own that uses `fgets` or otherwise to do the reading, in a loop with `realloc`, of course.

Comment: A tiny note: the very last line in a file *may* not end with an `\n` as well (fortunately, [there is a test for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20037822/2564301)).

Answer (score 0):

From the standards §7.19.7.2,

```
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

> The fgets function **reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by n** from the stream pointed to by stream into the
>   array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a
>   new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null
>   character is written immediately after the last character read into
>   the array.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx),

`fgets` reads characters **from the current stream position to and including the first newline character, to the end of the stream, or until the number of characters read is equal to n – 1, whichever comes first**. The newline character, if read, is included in the string.

So, yes `fgets` will read the rest of the line in next iteration if the it doesn't encounters the newline character within `sizeof(buffer)-1` range.

If you want to read the whole line in one shot, then it is better to go with `malloc` and, if needed, `realloc`ing the memory as per your needs.